# Merge list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**[PYTHON 2.7.1]**

I feel like the title is asking for the wrong thing but I'll go for it.

I want to be able to make two separate lists which take every other element, so far I've done it but I want to merge(?) the lists so it would look like (['a', 'c', 'e'],['b', 'd', 'f'])

I got this code:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
my_list2 = my_list[0::2]
my_list3 = my_list[1::2]
listprint=my_list2 + my_list3

>>> print listprint
['a', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: recognize that your desired output is some kind of "grouping" of two "lists". just use `print (my_list2, my_list3)` This is basically a tuple of 2 lists.

Comment: `[my_list2, my_list3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will solve the problem.

```
my_list2 = my_list[::2]
my_list3 = my_list[1::2]
listprint=[my_list2 , my_list3]
```

The `+` operator is overloaded for lists.
`list1 + list2` is equivalent to `list1.extend(list2)`

Comment: Thanks, not as simple as I thought. Though it was supposed to be a tuple of two lists since the task was to print out a tuple of two lists, I only got the print out and was to solve it from that, though Paroth Singh explained it above. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

You could have appended new lists to another new list and it would be much more readable and understandable for a new pythonist.

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
my_list2 = my_list[0::2]
my_list3 = my_list[1::2]
listprint = []
listprint.append(my_list2)
listprint.append(my_list3)
print(listprint)
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
[['a', 'c', 'e', 'g'], ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']]
```